# yii writing a resuable code for cascade dropDownMenu

Tags: ajax, yii

I wrote a three cascade dropDownLists that its listData are generated from the database models.
The lists are generated with an Ajax call to action in the controller based.

I want to reuse this code and to share it with more pages.

I tried to do the following:

1. Write it as a Custom Widget. 
   currently i use 'createurl' function that calls a function in the matching controller.
   I cant write JavaScript since i want to use the existing db models.
   In this case i need to write the action functions in an independent file - so should i write a controller? where should i place it?
2. Write it as a part of a module - but it seems overkill.

any suggestions,  i am sure that there is a right and simple way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create it as a [helper](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/165/understanding-autoloading-helper-classes-and-helper-functions/#hh1). A helper is just a class in the components which has no direct action in the M->C->V action flow but can be used in any controller, model, view, component, module, etc...
I would write a helper method to call it from the controller.

Another suggestion could be to extend CController to your own base controller and have your actual controllers, extend from your custom base controller. That way you can make it easily available in every controller, and then you just set some members that contain the models to use which you set in the actual controller.

If you need more help on this, find me on freenode #yii